# There are only 10 of us

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Make sense of what you see below and tell me the answer.

---

```
 vv< 
 .>^

 vv<v<v
 .>^>^.
 
 vvvv<  
 ...>^

 v
 . 
 
 vv<v<vv<
 .>^>^.>^
 
 vvv<v<v
 ..>^>^.
```

Comment: Wow ingenious puzzle!!! Never saw the direction of arrow contributing to the answer!

Comment: @DialFrost Thanks! I tried to make it a bit cryptic but to my surprise it was solved very fast.

Comment: People here solve puzzles within 1 hour, I am amazed by this community! :o

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is

> binary

> Draw lines from each cell in the direction of the arrow.
>  First makes 10, second 1001, 1110,  1, 10010, 11001
>  Read as binary  2, 9, 14, 1, 17, 25
>  Take the nth letter of alphabet: BINARY

Title refers to

> in binary, there are only 2 digits.

Comment: To be pedantic (I love it!), if 0 and 1 are the first two symbols of a counting system, then it does not matter the base: all of the counting systems will have 10 symbols. Hexadecimal has 10(hex) symbols: 16, octal has 10 (octal) symbols: 8.

Comment: I feel like the title could be a reference to the joke "There are 10 types of people, those who know binary and those who don't"